# How to hide Windows Phone 8.1 StatusBar in only landscape orientation?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm using this code for hide command bar for only landscape mode but I couldn't hide my status bar . I need to hide for watching full and clean screen youtube videos in my app .

```
void Current_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string CurrentViewState = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Orientation.ToString();        

    if (CurrentViewState == "Portrait")
        bottombar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    if (CurrentViewState == "Landscape")
        bottombar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: As you have CommandBar, I suspect that you are targetting Runtime, thus I've retagged your question - correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just found the solution. Here the codes.

```
void Current_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the new view state
    string CurrentViewState = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Orientation.ToString();
    var statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();

    if (CurrentViewState == "Portrait")
    {
        bottombar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ShowStatusBar();                      
    }

    if (CurrentViewState == "Landscape")
    {
        bottombar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        HideStatusBar();
    }
}

private async void ShowStatusBar()
{
    var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
    await statusBar.ShowAsync();
}

private async void HideStatusBar()
{
    var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
    await statusBar.HideAsync();
}
```

Comment: +1 - I would change your `async void` to `async Task` and await them in `Current_SizeChanged`.

Comment: @Romasz: Agreed. `async void` is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: I would also change the second `if` in `Current_SizeChanged` to an `else if` or just an `else`. Plus there is no need to declare `statusBar` in `Current_SizeChanged`